# Matplotlib/Pandas - Plot not reflective of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Trying to work out what is going wrong. I am using pandas to generate dataframes and matplotlib to plot a figure with 5 subplots.

Datasets are large xlsx sheets, all data is relative to depth below ground surface, duplicate depths have been removed, all number as text errors have been removed, although depth is shown between 0 - 60 ft data is not continuous over entire interval.

[What I am going for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyFC6.png)

[Current issue, x-axis not reflecting trends of data, line plotted straight through data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpyBD.png)

```
#Import libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd



#Import Excel Data
df1 = pd.read_excel  (r'017_FLD_and_FLS.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel (r'017_SUMD_SUMS.xlsx')


#Sort data for plotting
gam = list(df2['Natural Gamma'])
cal_Pre = list(df2['Caliper (pre-pumping)'])
cal_post = list(df2['Caliper (post-pumping)'])
fc = list(df2['Formation Conductivity'])
fr = list(df2['Formation Resistivity'])
neu = list(df2['Neutron'])
den = list(df2['Spherical Density (long-S)'])
htp = list(df1['Heat Pulse Flow'])
tp = list(df1['Static Fluid Temperature'])
t1 = list(df1['Pumping Temperature Run 1'])
t2 = list(df1['Pumping Temperature Run 2'])
t3 = list(df1['Pumping Temperature Run 3'])
 
depth = list(df2['Depth'])
depth_t = list(df1['Depth'])

#Test to verify subset
#print(gam)
#print (tp)





#Plot space
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,20))

# Caliper
ax01 = plt.subplot(151)
plt.plot(cal_Pre, depth, color="black")
ax01 = plt.gca()
ax01.invert_yaxis()
ax01.set_xlabel('Caliper (Inches)', color="black")
ax01.set_ylabel('Depth (Feet)', color="black")
plt.grid(True)

ax11 = ax01.twiny()
ax11.plot(cal_post, depth, color = 'green')  
ax11.set_xlabel('Gamma (counts)', color="green")
ax11.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor="green")
plt.grid(True, linestyle='--')

# Gamma 
ax02 = plt.subplot(152)
plt.plot(cal_Pre, depth, color="black")
ax02 = plt.gca()
ax02.invert_yaxis()
ax02.set_xlabel('Caliper (Inches)', color="black")
plt.grid(True)

# Neutron Density 
ax03 = plt.subplot(153, sharey=ax01)
plt.plot(den, depth, color = 'red')
ax03 = plt.gca()
ax03.invert_yaxis()
ax03.set_xlabel('Density (counts)', color = 'red')
ax03.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor="red")
plt.grid(True)

ax13 = ax03.twiny()
ax13.plot(neu, depth, color = 'blue')  
ax13.invert_xaxis()
ax13.set_xlabel('Neutron (counts)', color="blue")
ax13.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor="blue")
plt.grid(True, linestyle='--')

# Conductivity and Resistivity
ax04 = plt.subplot(154, sharey=ax01)
plt.plot(fc, depth, color="black")
ax04 = plt.gca()
ax04.invert_yaxis()
ax04.set_xlabel('Formation Conductivity(mS/cm)', color="black")
ax04.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor="black")
plt.grid(True)

ax14 = ax04.twiny()
ax14.plot(fr, depth, color = 'blue')  
ax14.invert_xaxis()
ax14.set_xlabel('Formation Resistivity (ohm-m)', color="blue")
ax14.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor="blue")
plt.grid(True, linestyle='--')

# Temperature and heat pulse
ax05 = plt.subplot(155)
plt.plot(htp, depth_t, color="black")
ax05 = plt.gca()
ax05.invert_yaxis()
ax05.set_xlabel('Heat Pulse Flow (gpm)', color="black")
ax05.set_ylabel('Depth (Feet)', color="black")
plt.grid(True)

ax15 = ax05.twiny()
ax15.plot(tp, depth_t, color = 'blue')  
ax15.invert_xaxis()
ax15.set_xlabel('Formation Resistivity (ohm-m)', color="blue")
ax15.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor="blue")

ax15 = ax05.twiny()
ax15.plot(t3, depth_t, color = 'blue')  
ax15.invert_xaxis()
ax15.set_xlabel('Formation Resistivity (ohm-m)', color="blue")
ax15.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor="blue")
plt.grid(True, linestyle='--')

fig.suptitle('GB017', fontsize=30, x=0.5, y=1.01)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Open to suggestions on making code more elegant but maintaining ease of figure modification.

Comment: My guess is that `plt.gca()` isn't giving the result you expect, since you are also using `plt.subplot()`. Try two means of debugging: 1. Remove subplot and try to get `twiny` working for just one of your plots. 2. Remove `plt.gca()` as you already have an `axes` object from `ax01=plt.subplot(151)`. Finally, please post all of your code. If it's very long, you can link to github or pastebin.

Comment: Understood, working on these now, thank you. I updated the post to include the entire code.